# Removing MKAnnotations in a thread-safe manner

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit, mkannotation

I'm new to objective-C, so pardon my ignorance:

I have a method declared in a class `WGMap : MKMapView` like so:

`- (void)cleanupMap {
    NSLog(@"Cleaning up the map!");
    NSSet* visible = [self annotationsInMapRect:[self visibleMapRect]];
    NSArray* all = [self annotations];
    NSMutableArray* discard = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (id<MKAnnotation> cur in all)
    {
        if (![visible containsObject:cur])
            [discard addObject:cur];
    }
    [self removeAnnotations:discard];
}`

The purpose is to clean up MKAnnotations not currently onscreen to save memory. I call this method periodically using a GCD dispatch timer.

I have another method running in parallel which occasionally adds MKAnnotations to the MKMapView. I've noticed that I occasionally get the following error:
`**** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: '*** Collection <__NSArrayM: 0x17025ed20> was mutated while being enumerated.'`

Sometimes, I will get a similar array out-of-range error.

How can I go about preventing this? I've tried making my class's (derived from MKMapView) `NSArray* annotations` property `atomic` rather than the default `nonatomic`, but it hasn't fixed the issue.

Comment: If the viewForAnnotation method is implemented and correctly using the view dequeue/re-use mechanism, you shouldn't need to do this yourself.  How do you know you have a "high memory usage" issue?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the exception because you are both iterating `self.annotations` and removing things from it inside that iteration.

Comment: I'm not removing it from within that iteration though; note that I select the MKAnnotations to be removed and add them to a separate NSMutableArray; I don't actually remove the annotations until after the iteration. The problem is that elsewhere in my app, annotations are being added to the map. I'm looking for a way to make this thread-safe to prevent the issue.